# Blank pages getting added, while merging multiple TIFF images into a single PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I am trying to merge multiple TIFF (multi-page) images into a single PDF having the same number of pages as the tiffs combined.

Using **PDFsharp** library,
I am merging 2 TIFF images each having 100 pages.

The **problem is** that the **1st image gets copied perfectly** into the PDF, **but starting from page number 101 all the pages are blank**. i.e. all the PDF pages starting from 2nd TIFF image are blank.

I am not sure what is causing this issue, can some one help me in fixing this issue?

This is my code. The `filePathWithFileName` will have the path of a Zip folder which has multiple TIFF images.

```
private static void MergeTiffToPDF(string filePathWithFileName)
{
  string[] sa;
  sa = Directory.GetFiles(filePathWithFileName.Substring(0, filePathWithFileName.LastIndexOf('.')));
  string destinaton = "C:\\Users\\someuser\\Desktop\\PDF_TIF_Document.pdf";
  PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
  foreach (string s in sa)
  {
    Image MyImage = Image.FromFile(s);
    for (int PageIndex = 0; PageIndex < MyImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page); PageIndex++)
    {
     MyImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, PageIndex);
     XImage img = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(MyImage);
     var page = new PdfPage();
     if (img.PixelWidth > img.PixelHeight)
     {
      page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
     }
     else
     {
      page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
     }
      doc.Pages.Add(page);
      XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[PageIndex]);
      xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
      xgr.Dispose();
     }
     doc.AddPage();
     MyImage.Dispose();
     }
     doc.Save(destinaton);
     doc.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[PageIndex]);
```

You have to add 101 to draw on the correct pages for the second file.

You see the images of the second file on pages 1 through 100 and the images from the first file are hidden.

Comment: Are the first file images are hidden or overridden?

Comment: Hidden. You can have multiple overlapping images, but PDFsharp does not replace images. If the images had transparent regions or different sizes then you could see both images.